# Surface Recording: Color Format Issues

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-mediacodec, stagefright, surfaceflinger

I am currently trying to record a `Surface` through the command line `screenrecord` utility. As per the implementation, the framework sets the color format of the `video encoder` component as `OMX_COLOR_FormatAndroidOpaque`. Hence, the `video encoder` is forced to retrieve the color format from the `gralloc` handle.

When this usecase is executed, the `video encoder` is encountering a `BGRA` `Surface`. The question I am trying to find an answer is thus:

In case of Miracast, the input to the encoder is received through `SurfaceMediaSource`. In case of `Surface` recording, the input surface for `MediaCodec` is provided through the `GraphicBufferSource` interface.

Should the color conversion from `RGB` to `YUV` space be handled inside the `video encoder` or is it better to introduce in `SurfaceMediaSource` which is the encoder's source abstraction for `gralloc` sources?

Comment: FWIW, Surface input to MediaCodec uses GraphicBufferSource (added in Android 4.3), not SurfaceMediaSource.

Comment: @fadden.. Thank you for pointing this out. I have updated my question to capture both scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my question, I investigated the codecs exposed as part of `AOSP` distribution and have found that the top-3 vendors viz., Qualcomm, Samsung and TI have adopted an internal color conversion to handle the `Surface` recording scenario. Some useful links are as below:

Qualcomm's `V4L2` based codec implementation:

- [Handling of `RGBA_8888` buffers in `omx_video_base` component](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/qcom/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/venc/src/omx_video_base.cpp#4290).

In Qualcomm video ecnoders, for `Surface` recording there is a color conversion and hence, the actual `YUV` data is present in the buffer pointers. There is a differentiation in handling between this scenario i.e. `Surface` recording and `Camera` scenario with a `Gralloc` source as can be observed from this [note](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/qcom/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/venc/src/video_encoder_device_v4l2.cpp#1858).

TI's Video Encoders:

- [`H.264` Encoder opening a color conversion module for `OMX_COLOR_FormatAndroidOpaque`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/ti/omap4xxx/domx/omx_proxy_component/omx_h264_enc/src/omx_proxy_h264enc.c#405).
- [`H.264` Encoder: Conversion from Platform Opaque to `NV12` format](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/ti/omap4xxx/domx/omx_proxy_component/omx_h264_enc/src/omx_proxy_h264enc.c#876).
- [`MPEG-4` Video Encoder: Opening of color conversion module for Opaque color format](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/ti/omap4xxx/domx/omx_proxy_component/omx_mpeg4_enc/src/omx_proxy_mpeg4enc.c#391).

Samsung Video Encoders:

- [`ARGB8888` conversion to `YUV420SemiPlanar`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/samsung_slsi/exynos5/exynos_omx/openmax/exynos_omx/component/video/enc/Exynos_OMX_Venc.c#318).

In Samsung's case, there is no differentiation between `gralloc` source scenarios as can be observed from [`Exynos_OSAL_GetInfoFromMetaData`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/hardware/samsung_slsi/exynos5/exynos_omx/openmax/exynos_omx/osal/Exynos_OSAL_Android.cpp#844).

Comment: It varies from device to device as well as vendor to vendor.  For example, on Nexus 5 with HWC 1.3 (qcom), the YUV conversion can be done by the hardware composer when the virtual display is being directed to a video encoder by screenrecord.  In some cases two different hardware components are capable of doing the RGB/YUV conversion, and there are power savings to be had by preferring one over another.

Comment: @fadden.. I completely agree with your view as I have some similar experiences. However, I am trying to understand the back-up strategies employed by the vendors mainly to answer one question: Should the encoder support color conversion or not?